# Problema pasando id por ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Buen día, tengo la siguiente tabla que tiene un botón que ejecuta dos funciones, la de obtenerDatosDocumento() que envía mediante ajax el id a una función php que retorna los datos que necesito, hasta ahí bien.

```
                    <?php while($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($respuesta)) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="display:none;"><?php echo $mostrar['doc_id'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $mostrar['doc_numero'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $mostrar['doc_antecedente'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $mostrar['doc_materia'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $mostrar['doc_fecing'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $mostrar['doc_fecemi'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $mostrar['doc_fecrec'] ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <button id="btnEditar"
                                    class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"
                                    data-toggle="modal"
                                    data-target="#modalActualizarDocumento"
                                    onclick="obtenerDatosDocumento(<?php echo $mostrar['doc_id']; ?>); enviar(<?php echo $mostrar['doc_id']; ?>);">Editar
                                </button>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                                        onclick="eliminarDocumento(<?php echo $mostrar['doc_id'] ?>)">
                                    Eliminar
                                </button>
                            </td>

                        

                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
```

La otra función (enviar()) tiene el propósito de enviar el mismo id pero a otro archivo php, por algún motivo ese archivo no recibe el id, a pesar de que el success me dice que el id si paso.

```
function obtenerDatosDocumento(doc_id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "doc_id=" + doc_id,
        url: "../procesos/documentos/obtenerDatosDocumento.php",
        success: function(respuesta) {
            respuesta = jQuery.parseJSON(respuesta);
            $('#doc_id').val(respuesta['doc_id']);
            $('#tpdIdu').val(respuesta['tpd_id']);
            $('#doc_numerou').val(respuesta['doc_numero']);
            $('#doc_antecedenteu').val(respuesta['doc_antecedente']);
            $('#doc_materiau').val(respuesta['doc_materia']);
            $('#doc_fecemiu').val(respuesta['doc_fecemi']);
            $('#doc_fecrecu').val(respuesta['doc_fecrec']);   
        }
    });
}

function enviar(doc_id) {
    console.log(doc_id);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "doc_id=" + doc_id,
        url: "documentos/otra.php",
        success: function(){
            console.log("Paso!");
        }
    });
 }
```

Finalmente este es el archivo que intenta recibir el id, pero no llega.

```
<?PHP
    $doc_id = $_POST['doc_id'];
    echo $doc_id;
?>
```

Consola y error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Codigo no es imagenes pls

Comment: Estás seguro de que es así como se pasan los objetos en un post en ajax? Creo que a `data` le debes asignar un un objeto que se parsee a un json válido, no un string así. Prueba a poner `data: { doc_id: doc_id}`, a ver si así se pasa.

Comment: Probé, pero tampoco funciono

Comment: Ya probaste viendo en el inspector de elementos que en el DOM que si te esté renderizando el `<?php echo $mostrar['doc_id']; ?>`?

Comment: ¿Realmente necesitas dos peticiones AJAX? ¿En qué momento se debe ejecutar la segunda?

Comment: Sí, dudo que sea la mejor manera para lograr mi objetivo final, pero es la que pude aplicar por mi escaso conocimiento, después de la primera.

Answer (score 0):

En comentarios mencionas que la segunda petición se debe ejecutar después de la primera, entonces, deja solo una acción en el botón:

```
<button id="btnEditar"
    class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#modalActualizarDocumento"
    onclick="obtenerDatosDocumento(<?php echo $mostrar['doc_id']; ?>););">Editar
</button>
```

Solo cuando la primera petición haya terminado con éxito, ejecutas la segunda:

```
function obtenerDatosDocumento(doc_id) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        data: { doc_id: doc_id },
        url: "../procesos/documentos/obtenerDatosDocumento.php",
        success: function(respuesta) {
            respuesta = jQuery.parseJSON(respuesta);
            $('#doc_id').val(respuesta['doc_id']);
            $('#tpdIdu').val(respuesta['tpd_id']);
            $('#doc_numerou').val(respuesta['doc_numero']);
            $('#doc_antecedenteu').val(respuesta['doc_antecedente']);
            $('#doc_materiau').val(respuesta['doc_materia']);
            $('#doc_fecemiu').val(respuesta['doc_fecemi']);
            $('#doc_fecrecu').val(respuesta['doc_fecrec']);
            // Todo bien, ejecutar la siguiente
            enviar(doc_id);
        }
    });
}
```

Adicionalmente, muestra en consola la respuesta de la segunda petición, donde supongo que la ruta no es correcta, porque falta `../procesos/`, que sí tienes en la primera. Es posible que tu sistema no devuelva encabezados 404 cuando no se encuentra el recurso y la petición llegue al `success`.

```
function enviar(doc_id) {
    console.log(doc_id);
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        data: { doc_id: doc_id },
        url: "documentos/otra.php",
        success: function(resp){
            console.log(resp);
        }
    });
 }
```

**Importante:** Es mejor usar `method` en vez de `type`, este es un *alias* del primero. También es recomendable crear los datos como objeto, es más legible que una cadena.

No entiendo porqué necesitas dos peticiones AJAX, si desde PHP puedes realizar las dos acciones, probablemente solo necesites un `include 'otra.php';` pero es difícil saberlo sin ver el código.

Comment: La ruta esta bien. El objetivo del "otra.php", es que reciba el 'doc_id' para poder realizar una consulta SQL y con eso devolver una especie de tabla, dado que en el archivo principal usare un require "otra.php". Hice las modificaciones que sugeriste, sin embargo sigue sin llegar el 'doc_id'  ya que hice el require "otra.php" en mi archivo principal y me da el error. Adjunto imagen de la consola y del error en la pregunta de arriba. Espero no ser tan confuso.